# Pass variables to fragment container in relay modern

Tags: relayjs, relaymodern

I'm using [Relay Modern](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/relay-modern.html) (compat). I have a fragment that contains a field that has one argument, but I can't find a way of passing the variable value from the parent component:

```
// MyFragmentComponent.jsx

class MyFragmentComponent extends Component {...}

const fragments = {
  employee: graphql`
    fragment MyFragmentComponent_employee on Employee {
      hoursWorked(includeOvertime: $includeOvertime)
      dob
      fullName
      id
    }
  `,
}

export default Relay.createFragmentContainer(MyFragmentComponent, fragments)
```

It will end up saying `$includeOvertime` is not defined. The context where this component is being rendered looks like this:

```
// MyRootComponent.jsx

class MyRootComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { employee } = this.props
    const includeOvertime = //... value is available here

    return (
      <div>
        <MyFragmentComponent employee={employee} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const query = graphql`
  query MyRootComponentQuery($employeeId: String!) {
    employee(id: $employeeId) {
      fullName
      ...MyFragmentComponent_employee
    }
  }
`

export default MyUtils.createQueryRenderer(MyRootComponent, query) // this just returns a QueryRenderer
```

With relay classic you would pass variables this way:

```
....
employee(id: $employeeId) {
  fullName
  ${MyFragmentComponent.getFragment('employee', variables)}
}
```

How can I achieve the same with relay modern?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `@argumentDefinitions` and `@arguments` directives seems to be the way to go. In relay versions before 1.4.0 `graphql.experimental` had to be used instead of `graphql`.

In the fragment definition:

```
const fragments = {
  employee: graphql`
    fragment MyFragmentComponent_employee on Employee
    @argumentDefinitions(includeOvertime: { type: "Boolean", defaultValue: false }) {
      hoursWorked(includeOvertime: $includeOvertime)
      dob
      fullName
      id
    }
  `,
}
```

If you want the argument to be required:

```
@argumentDefinitions(includeOvertime: { type: "Boolean!" })
```

In the parent component you should specify the arguments for the fragment like this:

```
const query = graphql`
  query MyRootComponentQuery($employeeId: String!, $includeOvertime: Boolean) {
    employee(id: $employeeId) {
      fullName
      ...MyFragmentComponent_employee @arguments(includeOvertime: $includeOvertime)
    }
  }
`
```

In [this page](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/refetch-container.html#example) in the official relay docs there is an example of directives for defining/passing arguments.

UPDATE:

> Since relay [version 1.4.0](https://github.com/facebook/relay/releases/tag/v1.4.0) `graphql.experimental` was deprecated and now all the features are supported by the regular `graphql` tag.

UPDATE:

> In relay [version 1.5.0](https://github.com/facebook/relay/releases/tag/v1.5.0) `graphql.experimental` was removed.